Image texture to multiple objects keeping ratio
I would like to apply an image texture to multiple objects in different sizes (it would be a wood texture for different board sizes). For example, I have a board in the size of x, 0.5x and 2x. I adjusted the image texture for the x size board, then I linked the material to the smaller and the bigger one. My problem is that the ratio keeps the same. So the image texture scaled up or down to the smaller or the bigger boards, so I can see the image adjusted in the x board on the other 2 boards, but just scaled. Is there a way to take in count the boards sizes? So on the x board I can see the whole image, on the 0.5x board I can see only the part of the image and on the 2x board I can see the image twice.
Thank you for your help in advance.

you can either make multiple materials and adapt the scale of the mapping node or you take the same material and change the uv map for every object.
